# How to use JFileChooser to find a file location

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Is there a method that i can use to simply find a file location? I'm trying allow the user to choose a file and open it, but I have to have the JFileChooser just choose the file and send the location to another method. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You want to "...simply find a file location..."?  You want to "...allow the user to choose a file..."?  But you have to have a JFileChooser?  A JFileChooser is a good way to let a user choose a file.  One thing that can make it easier for the user is to specify a directory for the JFileChooser to begin with.  If you want to do your own dialog to let the user choose a file, you could have a JList in a JDialog and you could add the file names to the JList in your own code.  I'm not sure exactly what you're asking though.  However you get it, use a File object..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) show show to do this:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
    "JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(parent);
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   System.out.println("You chose to open this file: " +
        chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
}
```

That's what `chooser.getSelectedFile()` is doing.  Take the result of that and pass it to another method.

Answer (score 3):

```
chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

// You can use 
// chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);  too

File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
```

Then Pass the String to the other method.

Comment: Why not pass the File reference? It has many useful methods associated with the file system, just saying

Comment: @MadProgrammer Agree. OP had asked to send about the location. So just gave the OP a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use TextArea to get paths of any file example here for Image File and the name of
object  TextArea is txtPath, and we make ActionPerformed to JButton named bChoose with the folowing method.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "gif");
fc.setFileFilter(filter);
fc.showDialog(bChoose, "Choose File");
String strPath = txtPath.getText() + "\n" + fc.getSelectedFile().toString();
txtPath.setText(strPath);
```