# open file docx in source file in java

Tags: java

I have the File Document.docx and put it in the "src/document/Document.docx"
When I use

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()){
    try{
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("src/document/Document.docx"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

it working in the neatbean but when I build it into the dist folder, it not work

so how can I open this file when I already builded it ?

i'm Vietnamese so my english not good, don't laught it .. Thanks :D

Comment: Do you get an exception? If yes, could you post it too?

Comment: java.lang.IlligalArgumentException .... file does not exist

Comment: Maybe it is not in the src folder. Have you tried the same path withouth **src/**? it works fine for me.

Comment: it works fine when I run on netBean but when I build into .jar file, it not work :(

Comment: Issue is with the path of the file............ look into this carefully.....

Comment: I think one solution could be getting the path of the running .jar and concatenate the path of your file. Check @Fab solution in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file).

Answer (score 0):

When you are in Netbean, the root directory used to find the files is the project dir.
Once you build your project, the root directory is not necessary the same. If you put your .jar in the root of the project, it should work. Otherwise you will have to copy your documment to dist/src/document/Document.docx

Comment: A better way would be to embbed the document.docx file in your jar, but I've never done it with netbean

Answer (score 0):

It may helps you:
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("Actual Directory/Document.docx"));

Comment: It work! But this is my project, I have to send it to Indian, if they put that folder at different Directory, it also not work :(

Comment: use [JFileChooser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774652/how-to-use-jfilechooser-to-find-a-file-location) then user can chose docx file.